# GenericADOException: could not insert

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to save my order object in the database that has a relationship many-to-one with the table pastaIndividual.

But, I'm getting this exception:

> Error: NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert:
>   [FrancosPoS.DBMapping.order][SQL: INSERT INTO order (price, cash,
>   credit, obs) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()] --->
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'order (price, cash, credit, obs)
>   VALUES ('123', 1, 0, 'Nhibernate');SELECT LAST_' at line 1

Here is my order mapping table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="FrancosPoS" namespace="FrancosPoS.DBMapping" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="order" table="order" lazy="true" >
    <id name="idOrder">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <set name="pastaIndividual" table="pasta_individual" cascade="save-update">
      <key column="idPastaI"/>
      <one-to-many class="pastaIndividual"/>
    </set>
    <!--<many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="pastaIndividual" class="FrancosPoS.DBMapping.pastaIndividual">
      <column name="idPastaI" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>-->
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="pastaCombo" class="FrancosPoS.DBMapping.pastaCombo">
      <column name="idPastaC" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="pastaFeast" class="FrancosPoS.DBMapping.pastaFeast">
      <column name="idPastaF" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="salad" class="FrancosPoS.DBMapping.salad">
      <column name="idSalad" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="drink" class="FrancosPoS.DBMapping.drink">
      <column name="idDrink" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="price">
      <column name="price" sql-type="decimal(8,4)" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="cash">
      <column name="cash" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="credit">
      <column name="credit" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="obs">
      <column name="obs" sql-type="varchar(150)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is my pastaIndividual mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="FrancosPoS" namespace="FrancosPoS.DBMapping" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="pastaIndividual" table="pasta_individual" lazy="true" >
    <id name="idPastaI">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="type">
      <column name="type" sql-type="varchar(25)" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="price">
      <column name="price" sql-type="decimal(8,4)" not-null="true" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I've tried on order mapping to use the `<set>` or just `<many-to-one>`, but the same error happen.

Maybe am I missing some inverse property?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using syntactic elements as column names without escaping, I suppose that is why your insert fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order is a reserved word. just add some back ticks to your class definition and NHibernate will escape the table name for you automatically.

```
 <class name="order" table="`order`" lazy="true" >
```

Comment: Thank you man!
Just to confirm the back ticks needs to be like that one that you typed ` not the simple quote like that '

Comment: This is true for column names too. I had the same issue with a property named `User`, which was solved by adding a `column` attribute with `User` in backticks.